# How to fix scoliosis for better/safer perfomence in a gym?

Tags: strength, muscle-gain, back

I'm 18 y.o. and I wanna fix my scoliosis for safer perfomance in a gym with heavy weights. What should I do for this? My left shoulder higher then my right shoulder[image: my back pic]

Comment: If you've actually been diagnosed with scoliosis, have you consulted with a physical therapist to improve your imbalance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scoliosis can only be "fixed" with surgery, which involves spinal fusion and is a drastic intervention that permanently limits spine movement. However scoliosis tends not to cause any problems other than aesthetics and possible back pain[<sup>1</sup>](http://doi.org/10.1001/jama.289.5.559), and it's also fine, or even beneficial, to participate in physical activity with scoliosis<sup>[2](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcm.2008.11.001),[3](https://doi.org/10.1155/2015/123848)</sup>.

So if you haven't been told by a doctor to avoid lifting weights, then I just wouldn't worry about it. And if you have, I'd get a second opinion.

Also, anecdotally, Lamar Gant had severe scoliosis and was one of the greatest powerlifters of all time!

[image: Lamar Gant rear flex]